# auto derive arguments from base argument Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, arguments, handle

I'm writing a *function* which have one value constant and others are *derived* in *Matlab*, I'm currently on that stage in which first *argument* is constant and others are *derived*,, but I want auto detection of *constant* and *derived* *arguments*.
Sample run is  `myfunc(7, @(b) -b,@(c) -c)`

**My function:**

```
function p = myfunc(varargin)
a=varargin{1};
b=varargin{2};
c=varargin{3};
res = a-1;
p = [a b(a) c(a)];
end
```

What I wants is to input like `myfunc(@(a) -a, 7,@(c) -c)` or `myfunc(@(a) -a, @(c) -c,7)` are also possible.

Comment: What it looks like you are asking is can Matlab work out which of the input arguments are functions and which are numbers, is that right? And why use `varargin` when `myfunc` only works with 3 inputs?

Comment: yeah matlab can do so, and I'v used `varargin ` so that to order the input by if-else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see if a variable is an anonymous function using

```
isa(a,'function_handle')
```

or see if it is a number using

```
isa(a,'numeric')
```

so you could set up a `switch` or a series of `if`'s based on what you get.